# NullPointerException only outside loop

Tags: java, android

I have a code snippet below and I absolutely don't understand why I get a NullPointerException. In the snippet below there are 3 Log.d lines.
I get an NPE at the first Log.d and at the third.
The second Log.d, inside the for loop works fine and I can receive all data from `gridview_names`.

`gridview_names` is declared at the top of the class as

```
private String[] gridview_names;
```

the snipped is from within the method

```
private ArrayList<ImageItem_Details> getData(int mode) {
```

which just formats for my GridView.

```
Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names NPE"+gridview_names[0]); // <--- NPE
        for (int i = 0; i <online_images.size(); i++) {
            try {
                if(!online_images.get(i).getData().get(Constants.DB_IMAGE_NAME).equals(gridview_names[0])) {
                    list.add(Integer.parseInt(online_images.get(i).getData().get(Constants.DB_IMAGE_POINTS).toString()));
                    Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names NO_NPE"+gridview_names[0]);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names NPE"+gridview_names[0]); // <--- NPE
```

Later but in the same method I have the following snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i <online_images.size(); i++) {
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            inner:
            for(int j = 0; j<online_images.size();j++) {
                try {
                    if(online_images.get(j).getData().get(Constants.DB_IMAGE_NAME).equals(gridview_names[i])) {
                        imageItems.add(new ImageItem_Details(online_images.get(j).getBitmap(), online_images.get(j).getData().getString(Constants.DB_IMAGE_NAME)));
                        break inner;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Here it works as well.

I usually understand why NPE's are caused, but the variable `gridview_names` exists, and it is full of data. I don't understand how this is caused.
Even if I try

```
Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names "+gridview_names.toString());
```

it is not working. In the loop it is working for some reason.

Edit:

Ok further testing done ... i absolutely cannot explain this error! please stay with me as i could minimalize the code and find out when it works and when it doesnt!
There is no way i understand this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <online_images.size(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names "+gridview_names[0]); //<--- NO NPE!!
}
for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names "+gridview_names[0]); //<--- NPE!!
}
```

Can someone pls explain how i get an NPE in the second case, but not in the first case?
I am running this code at the same time. it works if i comment out the line which causes the NPE

Comment: point out the line which is giving you the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Did you instantiate `gridview_names`? `private String[] gridview_names;` is just declaring an array, it's NOT creating the array object.

Comment: The NPE is at:Log.d(TAG, TAG+"Debug getData: gridview_names NPE"+gridview_names[0]);

Comment: @amit: It is working inside the loop. so it should be instantiated, shouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem. The function is called before online_images is filled. This did not come into play before i made the changes since the for loops never really played at the first function call since it became a loop that was like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
```

which never really run.

thx all